# How to upload images file in firebase in reactjs in newest update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having a trouble of how I will upload the images in firebase.
So basically I separated the firebase.js file and the imageupload.js file

It is something like this. in firebase file

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { storage };
```

And somethingg like this in my upload.js file

```
import {storage} from './firebase'

      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image)
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {},
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        },
        () => {
          storage
            .ref("images")
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              console.log(url)
            })
        }
      )
```

and giving me an error like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.storage.ref is not a function
```

And I don't understand what this means.. I already try some other information but it doesn't match very well how I will coded it up..Please help..this will be my final issue in my full stack website..I badly need help to get this done  thank you.

**UPDATED**

```
this is my firebase file
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage)

export { storageRef };
```

and this is my uploadfile.js

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

import { storageRef } from "./firebase";

      const uploadTask = ref(storageRef,`images/${image.name}`)
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          storageRef
            .ref("images")
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              console.log(url)
            });
        }
      );
```

but this time it show an error like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: uploadTask.on is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, the correct way to get ref is as follows.

Example with v9

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
const storage = getStorage();

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
const storageRef = ref(storage);
```

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference

Comment: is this in firebase file or what?

Comment: You can add it at firebase file and export the ref or you can call it at the place where you need it. For example you may want to point to the images ref with `const imagesRef = ref(storage, 'images')`

Comment: I really don't get it..can you please demo it in your code? I already tried your code but I don't know how I will implement it with the codes.

Comment: I'll show it in my edits.

Comment: There is my updated question sir. @someone special

Comment: Please check your codes, you are using `ref` on `ref`. If you want to use `ref` in uploadfile, then do not use `ref` in firebasefile

Answer (score 0):

You need to import "uploadBytesResumable" and "getDownloadURL"

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
```

and then change

```
const uploadTask = ref(storageRef, `images/${image.name}`);
```

to

```
const imageRef = ref(storageRef, `images/${image.name}`);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);
```

and doing that you will be able to use uploadTask.on(), something like this would look:

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL} from "firebase/storage";

import { storageRef } from "./firebase";

const imageRef = ref(storageRef, `images/${image.name}`);
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);

uploadTask.on(
   "state_changed",
   (snapshot) => {
     //your code...
   },
   (error) => {
     console.log(error);
   },
   () => {
     getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
       console.log(downloadURL);
     });
   }
);;
```